# jquery getResponseHeader always returns 'undefined'?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a a form that I am submitting via ajax.  I am using the jquery form plugin.  What I am trying to do is get the 'Location' header which is returned from my server.  I can see it in firebug.  But whenever I call the getResponseHeader() function in my success callback, it always returns 'undefined'..

Code:

```
form.ajaxForm({
  dataType: 'xml',
  data: {format: 'xml'},
  resetForm: true,
  success: function(xml,status,xhr){
    var location = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
    alert(location);
  });
```

location is undefined.  But I can see the 'Location' header in firebug. What am I missing? Even if I call getAllResponseHeaders() from the xhr object, it returns 'undefined'

Comment: Just to add:  This has been tested in both firefox and opera. Same results

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If this is a [CORS request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), you may see all headers in debug tools (such as Chrome->Inspect Element->Network), but the xHR object will only retrieve the header (via `xhr.getResponseHeader('Header')`) if such a header is a [simple response header](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology):

- `Content-Type`
- `Last-modified`
- `Content-Language`
- `Cache-Control`
- `Expires`
- `Pragma`

**If it is not in this set, it must be present in the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header) header returned by the server.**

About the case in question, if it is a CORS request, one will only be able to retrieve the `Location` header throgh the `XMLHttpRequest` object if, and only if, the header below is also present:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
```

If its not a CORS request, `XMLHttpRequest` will have no problem retrieving it.

Comment: This is the correct answer, if you have to use CORS and have these problems.

Answer (score 6):

An XMLHttpRequest will [transparently follow a redirect](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method), so the *final* request won't have the header, it's already followed that redirect and you're seeing the response headers from *that* request (not the initial request which had the `Location` header).

Comment: The server generates a 201 Created response.  I sure hope jquery doesn't interpret this as a redirect.  And firebug does not show a second request.

Comment: @Nik - It has a `Location` header though, right? that's a redirect.

Comment: It does have a location header, but if I understand the http response codes, 30x series means redirect. not 20x.  20x does not imply further action.  The location header should be informational.  But maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @Nik - Do you have a server I can see this on? You're *sure* the initial response is a 201, the initial one with the Location header...not the second?

Comment: After checking my server logs for my ruby on rails application, I do not see a second request after the 201 response. So xhr is not redirecting to the location.  That is fine, but maybe jquery is getting confused?  Any more ideas?  Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: @Nick - I do not have it on a live server unfortunately.  -edit-  Yes I am sure that the 201 is the only response. jQuery uses post to send to rails, rails creates the object and sends back a 201 with a location.

Comment: @Nik - jquery doesn't really control anything here, it's all the underlying XMLHttpRequest - I can't say for sure based on what syptoms you describe - would need to be able to hit the URL from here and look at the request/response.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help.  This is kind of a sensitive project, so I won't be able to make it live, but I might be able to make a mocked version with the same request/response cycle and problem.

Comment: @Nik - if you can do that please comment here, would be happy to take a look

Comment: I made as test application, using a standard ajax request sending only text fields.  It works as it should. I think the problem is related to the fact that I am using the forms plugin to do an ajax file upload.  The issue must be because it is using a hidden iframe. Not an actual xhr request. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing something similar using the rails/rest way of returning a 201 "created" with a Location header to the new object and an empty body. jQuery's ajax method will throw a "parseerror" when encountering this since its expecting json but getting nothing back. I simply catch the 201 redirect in my error callback like so:

```
function request_error(req, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{
    if (req.status == 201 ) {
        var created_loc = req.getResponseHeader('Location');
        console.log('(201) created: ' + created_loc);

        // ... manual redirect here i.e. issue another ajax request to created_loc
        return;
    }

    // ... handle an actual error here
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Just set dataType: 'text' as arg, and you can catch the 201 in the complete callback (or even better: jqXHR.done).