# Get url redirect from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, instagram

if I make this request by my browser :

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=e40f15***a66&redirect_uri=http://www.s***com&response_type=token
```

server respond me redirecting me to another website and I can see the new url in my browser

If I make this request by an Ajax call, how can I get the url where server has redirected me?I need it because Instagram authentication attach access token to this url. I'd like to highligth that I can see it in my browser url

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=e40f1**8a66&redirect_uri=http://www.s**ip.com&response_type=token',  

    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {   

        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },    
    error: function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);


    },

});
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10887732/227176

Comment: An ajax request will always follow redirects ?

Comment: Is the redirect URL your website?

Comment: Yes is a website selected by me and it is followed by an access token.I can see this in space for url in my browser but I need to catch it in my code